# TIN Interpolation Error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, interpolation, tin

I am having a problem with a contour file I got from a municipality. Two, actually.
I was using 3.16 and it would just hang up at 99% and then fail. This happened with both files.
I tried it again with 3.18 with one file and got this error. But I had chosen structured line, and was using a no-spaces file path on my local desktop, unlike a previous poster. (See images)
[image: TIN parameters screen]
[image: TIN log screen showing process and error message]
I have 16GB of RAM on a Windows 10 platform.
I can't create a DEM for the life of me, and it's stopped my work entirely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try and use **Points** for **Type**? If this fails, could you try to simplify your contour lines using **Simplify** algorithm?

Comment: It fails regardless of "Point", "Structured Lines" or "Break Lines". 
...
If I simplify the contour lines, will I still get an accurate surface?

Comment: Any TIN generation is an approximation. If you smooth the lines it gets less accurate too.